# Mysql How can i find max and min after sum a column

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

[This is my code from tables](http://prntscr.com/7gtp9w)

i want to select from it the first two and the last two rows as a result. is that possible?

in other words i want to select min and max of a column after it was summed. prefer two of each if possible
thanks a lot

```
`select A.prod_id, SUM(quantity) Total 
 from charging A 
  group by prod_id 
  order by total`
```

Comment: Your should include the code in your question.  The use of an external site means that your question is meaningless if the site is not available.  You should also include sample data and desired results.

Comment: the link is a printscreen with lightshot of my code and its result. it doesnt work?

Comment: Maybe you should remove the minmax tag from your post... Minmax is a concept of game theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery.  Because you didn't bother to include your query in the question, I am not going to re-type it.  For just the values:

```
select min(Total), max(Total)
from (<your query here>) s
```

For four rows with both values:

```
(select t.*
 from (<your query here>) t
 order by Total asc
 limit 2
) union all
(select t.*
 from (<your query here>) t
 order by Total desc
 limit 2
)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. it worked. and im sorry for my wrong post. first time :)